# GA goal match URL regular expression

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to setup a Goal URL with REGEX matching but it's not working.

The Url I'm trying to match is:

```
user/12345/edit?registration=1
```

with "12345" being the userid that changes.

```
user/[0-9]*/edit?registration=1
```

Should work, but doesn't. When I do an advanced search for pages with RegEx match (in the new GA interface) it shows no results. If I search for "contains" /edit?registration=1 it shows all the Urls.

What am I missing?

Comment: I had to escape the ? ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the question mark, like so:

user/[0-9]*/edit\?registration=1

As with regex's the question mark makes the preceding character optional, so you'd be matching:

- user/12345/ediregistration=1
- user/12345/editregistration=1

Test it on the advanced search (report filter) first, in case there's something else I've missed.